# how to do with java byte right or left shift to get 9 or 8 from a byte -104?

Tags: java, byte

In java byte ,`-104` is 10011000.

How to get the first 1001 as 9 and the last 4 bits 1000 as 8?

Thanks.

Comment: what you had done so far...Can you show some code??

Comment: byte b = -104;
        System.out.println((byte)((b>>>4)));
        System.out.println((byte)(b<<4));

Comment: 1001 as 9? what that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using **byte** primitive which is `16bit` in java means **-143** in binary number is actually `1111 1111 1001 1000`

**solution:**

You need to use `bitwise operator`(for masking) and `logical shift`(for shifting bits) to get your specific value.

```
byte b = -104; //10011000
System.out.println(((b & 0x00FF) >> 4)); //result 9
System.out.println(((b & 0x00FF) & 0x0F)); //result 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Study the bit operators `>>, <<, |, &`.

```
byte b = -104;

byte low_nibble = (byte)(b & 0x0F);
byte high_nibble = (byte)((b >> 4) & 0x0F);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, one approach to that would be using [`Integer.toBinaryString(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) and [`Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (with a radix of 2 for binary) -

```
byte b = -104;
String str = Integer.toBinaryString(b).substring(Integer.SIZE - Byte.SIZE);
int half = str.length() / 2;
byte left = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, half), 2);
byte right = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(half), 2);
System.out.printf("left = %d, right = %d%n", left, right);
```

Output is

```
left = 9, right = 8
```